# LWJGL with Eclipse i cannot fix the issue

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar

Hello so I'm new with libraries and i followed a Youtube tutorial 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HRaJXVuZjRM

and he imports the libraries there and it works, i did too as he did and it works (when in eclipse), however the problem comes later, when i export the app (i always click package but have tried extract and doesn't work either), i cannot open the .jar file.

I have seen already countless threads with this problem, i searched on google and found this:
http://wiki.lwjgl.org/index.php?title=Setting_Up_LWJGL_with_Eclipse

which is basically what he did in the video, i open my manifest file inside of the jar file with 7zip and i get this:

``

> Manifest-Version: 1.0
>
> Rsrc-Class-Path: ./ jinput.jar jogg-0.0.7.jar jorbis-0.0.15.jar lwjgl.
>
> jar slick.jar
>
> Class-Path: .
>
> Rsrc-Main-Class: com.tutorial.main.Game
>
> Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader"
>
> And if i run the application with the console i get this error:
>
> Sun Dec 06 16:42:40 COT 2015 INFO:Initialising sounds..
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>
> ```
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>
>     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
> ```
>
> Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in
>   java.library.path
>
> ```
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
>
>     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
>
>     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
>
>     at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:73)
>
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>
>     at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)
>
>     at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:95)
>
>     at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:112)
>
>     at org.lwjgl.openal.AL.<clinit>(AL.java:59)
>
>     at org.newdawn.slick.openal.SoundStore$1.run(SoundStore.java:295)
>
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>
>     at org.newdawn.slick.openal.SoundStore.init(SoundStore.java:292)
>
>     at org.newdawn.slick.Sound.<init>(Sound.java:54)
>
>     at com.tutorial.main.AudioPlayer.load(AudioPlayer.java:17)
>
>     at com.tutorial.main.Game.<init>(Game.java:41)
>
>     at com.tutorial.main.Game.main(Game.java:159)
>
>     ... 5 more
> ```

``

I suppose it means that it cannot find the libraries and stuff but i have already tried creating a lib folder and a natives folder inside, placing the stuff there and changing the manifest into this:

"
Manifest-Version: 1.0

Class-Path: lib/jinput.jar lib/jogg-0.0.7.jar lib/jorbis-0.0.15.jar

lib/lwjgl.jar lib/slick.jar

Main-Class: com.tutorial.main.Game
"

But it doesn't run it either, i really don't know what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a temporal fix for anyone with this problem, remove the natives from eclipse (the native link) and then export and use JarSplice to generate the .jar, if you are using music and cannot open it just open the .jar create the folder you used for your files in your workplace (mine was res) and then drag the music files in there instead of outside... this is temporal since I'm sure there's better ways to do it.